# How to interpret test Welch and which tests post hoc should be used after test Welch

Tags: statistics, anova, variance, statistical-test, posthoc

I use ANOVA, including the Levene test, unidimensional significance tests, descriptive statistics and the Tukey test. I have some doubts about what happens when the assumption of homogeneity of variance is not met in the Levene test. In many of the available materials I found the information:

"Basic assumptions of ANOVA tests:

- Independence of random variables in the populations (groups) under consideration.
- Measurability of the analysed variables.
- Normality of the distribution of the variables in each population (group).
- Homogeneity of the variance in all populations (groups).
  If one of the first three assumptions is not met in the analysis of variance, the non-parametric Kruskal-Wallis test should be used. If the assumption of homogeneity of variances is not met, the Welch test should be used to assess the means."

If we had heterogeneous variances and a non-normal distribution then we would apply the Kruskal-Wallis test, right? On the other hand, what if we have both heterogeneous variances and a normal distribution, do we use the Welch test? If we do the Welch test, how should it be interpreted and what tests are subsequently recommended to see statistically significant differences between groups?

I would be very grateful for an answer

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming forum (see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). For statistical methodology and interpretation question, consider posting the question on stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.